# Which database should be using for my specific goal

Tags: database-recommendation

**Introduction:**

I am trying to figure out what kind of database I should use for my project to get the best speed possible.

**Background:**

I am not sure if MySQL is the best solution, but I will use MySQL as an example to explain the data that I currently have.  The data currently (or will) be arranged in 2 tables.

Table 1 has have 3 columns and Table 2 has have 1 column.  Both tables will have around 1 billion rows each.

The project will get the first value from Table 2 and check if it exists in the first column of Table 1.

This project is currently running on a computer which has a mechanical drive.

Rough estimates suggest at the data will use around 500GB of drive space.

**Goals:**

1. To be able to insert the data into the tables as fast as possible,
2. To be able to compare each column in Table 2 to see if the same value exists in column 1 of Table 1 as fast as possible.

**Progress:**

At the moment, I am inserting the data into a MySQL database and batching the inserts into groups of 1000, which is averaging to about 200 inserts per second.  At this rate, it will take about 2 months to generate and insert the 1 billion records..

**Benchmark:**

The process of generating the data and inserting the data is using around 5% CPU, around 1GB RAM of the 16GB available, and when checking the disk IO, it is averaging about 2MB/s.  So my guess is that the mechanical drive is the bottleneck.  I can constantly hear it seeking away.

**Question:**

With the possible mechanical drive as the bottleneck in mind (correct me if I am wrong about this being the bottleneck), is MySQL the best option to achieve the 2 goals above as fast as possible, or is there a different type of database I should be considering and using instead?

Comment: Based on your description, you don't need table 2. You can add a column, perhaps named "observed."  That new column could contain a count of the number of times the value in column 1 has been observed.  Once table 1 is populated, you only need to do an update.

Comment: Additional information request to improve your row insert rate per second.  
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## XY Problem

I see too many *Red Flags* in your post to leave a comment.  In general, you seem to have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

## Problem 1

> I can constantly hear it grinding away.

STOP! RUN! DO NOT WALK! GET THIS HD REPLACED ASAP!!

If it is really making a *grinding* sound, then your HD is already toast.

## Problem 2

> it is averaging about 2MB/s

Modern Hard drives can achieve an IO transfer speed in the [600 MB/s range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_3.0_(6_Gbit/s,_600_MB/s,_Serial_ATA-600)).  Your observation means you have a non-DB related issue.

Make sure you run your IO benchmark *outside* of the DB. If your Data Process is not coming close to that measured transfer speed, then the bottleneck is not with the disk IO.

Usually, it is with the way you are processing your data.

## Problem 3

> averaging to about 200 inserts per second.

Ahh!! Now we are getting to the heart of the problem.

This is usually an indication that you are using a *slow-by-slow* process method to load data.

You need to load data in *Bulk*.  When you do that, you should see `INSERT` rates closer to 1M rows in mere *seconds*. Your IO transfer rates should then be closer to what you measured outside of the DB.

## Problem 4

> With the possible mechanical drive as the bottleneck

Use a [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) setup to improve IO/IOPS performance.  This applies to both HDDs and SSDs.

## Problem 5

> 2. To be able to compare each column in Table 2 to see if the same value exists in column 1 of Table 1 as fast as possible.

Relational Databases are built based on [Relational Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). If you can change your Business Requirement to be a Relational Algebra question, then the solution becomes a *no-brainer*

I suggest you Change your Requirements so that

1. The values in `Table_1.Column_1` need to be `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`
2. The database is not allowed to accept data for `Table_2` that does not comply with the stated requirements.

From there, the answer becomes "Use a `FOREIGN KEY` on each of the columns in `Table_2` that points to the `PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_1.COLUMN_1)`".

The overhead for the FK check during `INSERT` should be minimal.

I am unaware of any of the major relational databases that cannot handle a 1 Billion row child table and/or 1 Billion row parent table. So, MySQL *should* be just fine. (BTW - "List of Software" questions are *off topic* for this forum.)

Comment: Problem 1: Sorry, grinding was the wrong word to use.  I should have said "seeking" sounds.  I will comment on the rest asap.  Thank you for the detailed answer.